# Liferay 7 Eclipse IDE override default categories filters query

Tags: liferay, liferay-7, liferay-ide

I’m looking for a way to override the default category filter behaviour for ***Asset Publisher widgets*** (point 3 of my previous question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56949208/liferay-7-eclipse-ide-override-default-categories-behaviour)).
As far as I understand in the ***Setup > Asset Section > Filter*** a rule based on categories will look for all ***source > asset type*** components which match the selected categories.
I would like to know where is default query stored and how it is possible to modify it in order to introduce other custom criteria.

**Update:** 
I can create a Liferay module project fragment, but I wasn't able to retrieve the correct OSGi bundle and relative file to override the default query filter behaviour.

Comment: AssetPublisher is one of the most complex widgets/portlets in Liferay. To change it means a lot less work than your original plan in the linked question, but it'll still be a maintenance nightmare for bringing in future updates (e.g. security fixes) or upgrades to the next version. I'd recommend to write your own portlet to filter what you actually need. This won't need all of AssetPublisher's bells and whistles, and maintaining an additional piece of code should be way easier than maintaining a diff of the most complex UI element there is.

Comment: My goal is just to change the default category filter behaviour from retrieving all web contents with a specified category to retrieve all web contents with the same category or any of its children categories.
This is why I'm looking for a way to update the default query hoping the module fragment could be a good solution.

Comment: Isn't that what AssetPublisher does anyway? That's the whole point of hierarchical categories

Comment: No, it doesn't. 
Creating a parent category A and children category A1, if your content X has assigned A1 and you select a filter in the asset publisher for all content with parent category A it won't show.
However, I'm just looking to a way to override the default filter query (if it exists) in order to customize it in future in different ways.

Comment: I lost track of this. I believe that this behavior is a bug. I've reproduced it today and filed it at https://issues.liferay.com/browse/LPS-100327. At least earlier versions behaved correctly with hierarchical categories

Comment: Thank you for the information, I've found this behaviour on 7.x versions as you've reported on LPS-100327.